# Question about the stochastic differential equation in the Merton model

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance, sde, merton-model

in the following stochastic differential equation merton model we have $$\frac{ds}{s}=(\alpha-\lambda k)dt+\sigma dW+dq$$

where $\alpha$ is the instantaneous expected return on the stock; $\sigma^2$is the instantaneous
variance of the return, conditional on no arrivals of important new information (i.e.,
the Poisson event does not occur); $dW$ is a standard Gauss-Wiener process; $q(t)$ is
the independent Poisson process ; $dq$ and $dW$ are assumed to be
independent; ¸ is the mean number of arrivals per unit time;$ k=E(Y-1)$ where
$(Y-1)$ is the random variable percentage change in the stock price if the Poisson
event occurs; and $E$ is the expectation operator over the random variable $Y$.

now my question is why we use $E(Y-1)$ and we dont use $E(Y)$ i.e I want to know What is the purpose of -1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if $Y=1$ the stock price doesn't change since it's a percentage change not an absolute, so we have to subtract one when drift compensating.

See my book Concepts etc for my discussion.